# Magento Observer to block spam orders not working

Tags: magento-1.9, module, orders, event-observer

**I'm facing some issues with orders placed by bots.**

[image]

I noticed that all orders are made by a specific phone number and also by a specific street. So I looked for a way to block orders that are made with that phone number or this street.

I found the following link https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/.
I followed the steps to create an observer with the event sales_order_place_before, to compare the parameters sent in the order to the parameters that I want to block.

1. I created the file Blockbots_Observer.xml on /html/app/etc/modules;
2. I created the file Config.xml on /html/app/code/local/Blockbots/Observer/etc;
3. Finally, I created the file Observer.php on /html/app/code/local/Blockbots/Observer/Model;

After all these steps, the implementation did not work (I am still receiving orders from bots).

Here is the code on files:

**Blockbots_observer.xml:**
[image]

**Config.xml:**
[image]

**Observer.php:**
[image]

#### What could be wrong with implementation? Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Use Webfirewall that is the best solution.You have to prevent the bot at network level, not Application Level

Comment: This is not a suitable fix, as bots often come in swarms with each having its own address. We have the same issue, bot swarms 'tasting' credit cards on our store, always using the same address but each having a different IP.

Answer (score 0):

block the bot ip Address range from accessing your website.

in .htaccess file:

```
order allow,deny
deny from yourparticularip
```

or you can do it in your index.php

```
$banned = array('xx.xxx.x.x');
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $banned))
{
exit();
}
```

here is the reference:https://bobcares.com/blog/magento-block-ip-address/

Comment: This is not a suitable response to this issue, as bots usually come from many different IP addresses. Block the street, zip, or phone number of an individual scammer is the easiest way to block them.